# Do new units get the bonuses of previous unique units?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

Does the new unit (one you can produce) have theses effects, or is it only upgraded ones? example: If I upgrade my Russian cossack (+25% damage against damaged units) to a GDR, it will keep this bonus. If I build a new GDR, will it have the same bonus? Or should you stock up on unique units while you can so later they will have superior upgrades to new ones?

Comment: In the case of Japan, I know that you get to build the Samurai even after getting their upgraded counterpart (riflemen I think?), so even though you can upgrade Samurai on the spot you can still order their production. That being said, Samurai are at best a sidegrade to riflemen and significantly outdated by infantry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only units that were upgraded from the unique unit would get the bonus.

Comment: So I'll stock up on the unique units then.